# Cannot able to access the database from react app running on my phone connected to local network

Tags: reactjs, database, spring-boot, backend, web-development-server

I have created a react app. It is running on Port:3000. for the same i have created a backend with the help of springboot and java which is running on Port:8080.

By using npm start in vs code i was able to run the react app perfectly on my pc. but when i tried to access the same app through my phone connected to the same network using the ip address of my pc:3000. i see that i can access the react part but seems like i am not able to access the database part. i.e. backend part on phone. i am getting network error on my phone.

When i checked further by accessing pc_ip_address:8080/api on phone i am getting the correct response back in json format.

I have no idea what is causing this app to not have access to database through phone.

Please share your thought i would really appreciate your support.

I am expecting to have access to database from my phone as well when i am accessing react app through my phone.

Answer (score 0):

How do you handle your Backend request in the React app?
Do you make api request in react like this: ("http://localhost:8080/...")

This may be causing the Problem. You should maybe look into proxying your api request (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)